# Google sheets formula - lookup (alphabetical sort)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a formula, that gets me the specific value(s) from row in another table. The formula I've created

```
=LOOKUP(E5;Ingredients!$A$6:$B$49;Ingredients!$F$6:$F$49)
```

gives me false results. **But when I sort the values by alphabet the results are correct.**

Is there some way to **create a formula that is not dependent on alphabetical sort** of source table?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the original table?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet or use vlookup with 0 at the end

Comment: 1. If you use the third parameter, then second argument of `LOOKUP` should be a single row or a column, but you have two columns `$A$6:$B$49`. 2. It should be sorted. 3. If you have you keys to search through in column `A:A` then try `=VLOOKUP(E5; {Ingredients!$A$6:$A$49, Ingredients!$F$6:$F$49}; 2; False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en-GB

"Notes:

The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or search_result_array is sorted. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP or other related functions if data is not sorted."

Personally, I've never really used the lookup functions because of issues like this, so I'm a bit rusty on the specifics of how they all work. My go-to is the INDEX MATCH solution, which might be something like

```
=index(Ingredients!$F$6:$F49, match(E5, Ingredients!$A$6:A$49))
```

What I'm also not sure about is how Lookup is supposed to work when you're giving it more than one column as the input, though; you're giving it A and B - I thought that syntax was for an array where the output comes from the last column, and I don't know what happens if you then specify the output column as well, as you've done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your formula. It is working only for alphabetical sort of table with Ingredients. If not sorted there's an error thrown - unable to find value in match formula.

Comment: This `INDEX`-`MATCH` method should work if you give `MATCH` 0 as its third parameter: `=index(Ingredients!$F$6:$F49, match(E5, Ingredients!$A$6:A$49, 0))`